# Problem with printing length of permutations in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm starting out learning Haskell and I'm having a difficult time because the error messages are extremely cryptic. In particular, I'm not understanding the error messages when I run this code that is supposed to print the number of permutations of a string,

```
import Data.List

main::IO()
main = do
        str <- getLine
        print putStrLn $ length $ nub $ permutations str
```

The error message I get is

[image]

However, when I run it in the REPL I get no such error:

[image]

Comment: `print putStrLn`?

Comment: @DanielWagner I originally put in the print because I thought that the types didn't match because of my misunderstanding of monads. However, with or without the print it still doesn't compile.

Comment: The error that arises with `print` *or* `putStrLn` is more interesting than the one generated by the obviously incorrect `print putStrLn`. Make sure your error message reflects the code in the question as well.

Comment: For future questions, please post text as text, and not as an image. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: You could, if you wanted to respect convention, remove your png and replace with text. This helps future users.

Answer (score 6):

```
print putStrLn $ length $ nub $ permutations str
```

is parsed by Haskell as

```
print putStrLn ( length ( nub ( permutations str )))
```

i.e. it calls `print` with 2 arguments, `putStrLn` and `length (nub (permutations str))`.

You want to call it with just one parameter, so one more pair of parens is needed for that:

```
print ( putStrLn ( length ( nub ( permutations str ))))
```

This can be achieved with `$`s by just adding one more, as

```
print $ putStrLn $ length $ nub $ permutations str
```

This addresses only the syntactic issues with your code.

Of course `print` with `putStrLn` is redundant. `putStrLn` already does all the output `print` would do (and even outputs one more newline after that).

On the other hand `putStrLn` expects a string, but `length` produces an integer. To convert it to a string, the function `show` can be used, which `print` calls internally on its own.

So it is either

```
print            $ length $ nub $ permutations str
```

or

```
putStrLn $ show $ length $ nub $ permutations str
```

as can be seen in GHCi:

```
> :t print           . length . nub . permutations
  :: Eq a => [a] -> IO ()

> :t putStrLn . show . length . nub . permutations
  :: Eq a => [a] -> IO ()
```

If it has type, it makes *some* sense, at least.

Answer (score 4):

`putStrLn` takes a parameter of type `String`, as evidenced by [its signature](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.17/base-4.12.0.0/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn).

`length` returns an `Int`, as evidenced by [its signature](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.17/base-4.12.0.0/Prelude.html#v:length).

So obviously, trying to pass the result of `length` as a parameter to `putStrLn` causes a type mismatch. `Int` does not match `String`. As simple as that.

The function `print`, on the other hand, takes parameter of any type (see [signature](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.17/base-4.12.0.0/Prelude.html#v:print)), as long as that type has a `Show` instance, which `Int` does. So you can just replace `putStrLn` with `print`:

```
print $ length $ nub $ permutations str
```